# AbsoluteToLocal does not work on Android as on Windows

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to get coordinates inside of a control 1 by using another control 2 that's in front of it. To simplify, Control 1 is used as a background, and control 2 is a small rectangle that can be moved above control 1. When the user presses a button, I want to get the part of the background (control 1) that the rectangle (control 2) is over, and to achieve that I'm using AbsoluteToLocal and LocalToAbsolute. Furthermore, I want to save the selection into a 125x125 bitmap,  no matter how big the user's selection actually is. Here's the code:

```
function TForm1.CropImage: TBitmap;
var
  LSourceBitmap: TBitmap;
  LDestinationBitmap: TBitmap;
  LSourceRect: TRectF;
  LDestRect: TRectF;
begin
  LSourceBitmap := Control1.MakeScreenshot;
  LSourceRect.TopLeft := Control1.AbsoluteToLocal(Circle1.LocalToAbsolute(TPointF.Create(0, 0)));
  LSourceRect.BottomRight := Control1.AbsoluteToLocal(Circle1.LocalToAbsolute(TPointF.Create(Circle1.Width, Circle1.Height)));

  LDestRect := TRectF.Create(0, 0, 125, 125);
  LDestinationBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  LDestinationBitmap.Width := 125;
  LDestinationBitmap.Height := 125;
  LDestinationBitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  LDestinationBitmap.Canvas.DrawBitmap(LSourceBitmap, LSourceRect, LDestRect, 1);
  LDestinationBitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  LSourceBitmap.Free;
  Result := LDestinationBitmap;
end;
```

This function works just as it should on Windows, but when tried on Android, it gets a totally different part of the control 1. Problem is that I cannot debug the values since they depend on the screen's resolution.

Maybe I'm using the functions incorrectly, but I can't see the problem in code here. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you would need to give a complete working example so that we can see exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: @XylemFlow the code would just make the question more complex and harder to understand, at least from my point of view. But to be more precise, the mentioned control 1 (background) is actually TImage, and I'm using MakeScreenshot to create a TBitmap, and the code written above is for getting the coordinates of Control 2 which I use for getting that certain part of the TBitmap.

TLDR: It's a tool for cropping (selecting a certain part of) an image.

Comment: @vrelisean it’s best to provide a a sample or some code for which some can reproduce the problem. When, as you say, your code is so complex, there’s no telling where it goes wrong, even when you assume the problem lies with the small code sample you provided.

Comment: @R.Hoek you're right. I've provided more code and a more detailed explanation.